# How to have shared variables across JenkinsFiles

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a set of child JenkinsFiles which get called from a main JenkinsFile. The main JenkinsFile defines a few variables, which I wan't to avoid defining in the child JenkinsFiles.

Is that possible?

Example of main JenkinsFile:

```
#!groovy

String var1 = "something"
String var2 = "something"

load 'JenkinsFile-child1'
load 'JenkinsFile-child2'
```

JenkinsFile-child1:

```
#!groovy

echo var1
echo var2
```

Comment: what is it `load` - is it a jenkins pipeline function? because in groovyshell it's `:load`

Comment: `load` executes the jenkinsfile in place. It's like python's import statement.

Answer (score 0):

pipeline script:

```
node{
    load 'main.groovy'
}
```

main.groovy

```
var1 = "world"
load 'child.groovy'
```

child.groovy

```
echo "hello $var1"
```

will print `hello world`

the key that in script you can declare variable (field) for current scope (for the whole script class)

and you do if with assignment to undeclared variable in script.

normally the [following annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) also should work, but unfortunately not:

```
import groovy.transform.Field;
@Field String var1 = "world";
```